# how to detect who changed mail status in shared IMAP mailbox

Tags: debian, logs, imap

Is that possible to know from the imap / dovecot logs which user performed which operation (ie. delete, status change) on mail in shared IMAP mailbox?

Comment: What means “which user”? From which IP did (s)he connect, or?

Comment: I imagine that's only info obtainable - afaik there is no such thing like user agent for email clients (edit: and timestamp, of course, which helps to pinpoint the user)